# in python how do I decompose a rotation matrix to a quaternion? (preferrably using the euclid library)

Tags: python, matrix, quaternions

I have started experimenting with the [euclid module for python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/euclid) .  I am now to the point where I want to take an arbitrary rotation matrix and decompose it into its quaternion form.

The formulas are available in a couple of places on the web (like http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/ ), but I was hoping there was an implementation somewhere inside the euclid library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually discovered the following technique:

```
q2 = euclid.Quaternion.new_rotate_matrix(m)
```

that decomposes a rotation matrix into a quaternion.  You might still have to worry about the fact that `q` and `-q` both represent the same orientation, especially if you are keyframing rotations in a 3D animation.